# Overloaded == function not getting called

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading, equals-operator

I am currently working on overloading the == operator for my linked list. I have the operator in my header set up like the following:

```
class sqrlst
{
public:
std::vector<int> vlist;

bool operator == (iterator const & rhs )
{
     return this->iter == rhs.iter;
};
```

I then created a method in my header file with the following code

```
void test()
    {
        bool flag;
        if (vlist.begin()==vlist.begin())
        {
            flag=true;
        }
    };
};
```

However when this method is called it does not go to my overloaded == operator function when it hits the if statment. When I put the debug point on the overload function it says that the line will not be reached.

Any tips or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: vlist is a list of ints.

Comment: What type does `begin()` return?

Comment: it looks like you have defined `operator==` for `sq_list`. But the comparison you are performing looks like is on `iterators`. If so, `operator==` will not be called. It will be called if you do `vlist==vlist`.

Comment: @Johnston: The edited code still doesn't make sense. You are using `rhs.iter` where as `rhs` itself is supposed to be an `itertaor`. Can you post real compilable code with which the problem is reproduciible?

Comment: @Naveen I was wrong it suppose to be an iterator. (I made the changes) but it still seems to not reach that overloaded function

Comment: @Johnston: By any chance `sq_list::begin` returns a `const_iterator` instead of an `iterator`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `std::vector` member functions `begin()` and `end()` returns iterator of type `std::vector<T>::iterator`, or `` `std::vector<T>::const_iterator ``, depending on whether the vector object is `const` or non-const. Whatever it is, the iterator type is not defined by you. Overloading `==` in your class `sqrlist` does nothing. The overload `==` should be a member of vector's iterator class, which you're **not** allowed to edit.

Also note that vector's iterator class has already overloaded `==` and `!=` operators. So when you compare iterators using `==`, it is invoking a member function of vector's iterator class.

Comment: i believe your correct that it should be an iterator. i changed it back and i added the const but my break point still says it wont be reached

Comment: vlist was my list of values and sq_list was my class --my mistake for having that in there before

Comment: I appreciate your help! I have now updated what my code is now (still same problem) but im closer i think now. Im trying to compare the two interators.

Comment: @Johnston: Please provide all informations. What is the type of `vlist`? Is it `const` qualified?

Comment: @Johnston: POST THAT in your answer.

Comment: is there any other information i can provide you that would help?

Comment: @Johnston: `vlist` is a list of ints, is not any information. You write that code, so I will see it myself. why do you mean by list of ints? how did you define it? who define it?

Comment: I added in how i create my list. Hope this clears things up. If theres anything else that will make it more clear let me know